# Can I modify ts.forEachChild() in definition typescript files (d.ts) from typescript services to pass another object as its parameter?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to get the syntax tree of a definition typescript file linked to a single object (the tree connected from root node) and I am not able to pass another object through `ts.forEachChild()`. How can I achieve this? 
P.S. - basically I want to get an abstract syntax tree object in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know typescript parser provides a function which produces an AST object for you. You can lookup more details [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/compiler/parser.html). If you would like to traverse that ast you can use a project like [tspoon](https://github.com/wix/tspoon) (shameless plug) to write a visitor. You may also view how tspoon uses [createSourceFile](https://github.com/wix/tspoon/blob/master/src/transpile.ts#L68).

```
var ast = ts.createSourceFile('foo.ts', sourceCode, ts.ScriptTarget.ES5, true);
//carefule, parseDiagnostics is an internal key and may break in the future. 

if (ast['parseDiagnostics'].length > 0) {
    return ast['parseDiagnostics'];
}
// code which uses the AST
```